# Error XDG0062: Failed to set "Content". on MUXC Navigation View

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm trying to make a navigation view with MUXC in my app but is donesn't work:

> Error XDG0062: Failed to set "Content".

XAML Code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="XizSoft.Views.Pages.TestPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:XizSoft.Views.Pages"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <muxc:NavigationView    x:Name="nvSample9"
                            Header="This is Header Text"
                            PaneDisplayMode="Left"  
                            IsSettingsVisible="False">
        
        <muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="Browse" Tag="SamplePage1" Icon="Library" />
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="Track an Order" Tag="SamplePage2" Icon="Map" />
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="Order History" Tag="SamplePage3" Icon="Tag" />
        </muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <muxc:NavigationView.FooterMenuItems>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="Account" Tag="SamplePage4" Icon="Contact" />
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="Your Cart" Tag="SamplePage5" Icon="Shop" />
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="Help" Tag="SamplePage5" Icon="Help" />
        </muxc:NavigationView.FooterMenuItems>
        
        <Frame x:Name="contentFrame9" />
        
    </muxc:NavigationView>
    
</Page>
```

> Target: Universal Windows version 2004
> Min. Target: Universal Windows version 1809

Does anyone knows how to solve this? Is this a problem in my code or in the platform?

Comment: Can you give us the TargetSDK, MinTargetSDK and the version of the Microsoft.UI.Xaml library please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this is not required but have you tried to encapsulate your frame in the Content property of your NavigationView ?

```
 <muxc:NavigationView.Content>

      <Frame x:Name="contentFrame9" />

 </muxc:NavigationView.Content>
```

With the Target and MinTarget SDK, my app successfully display your page :
[image]

I have referenced the last version of Microsoft.UI.Xaml library :
[image]

Comment: Can you give us the TargetSDK, MinTargetSDK and the version of the Microsoft.UI.Xaml library please ?

Comment: Updates the question with that info but im unable to find the Micrososft.Ui.Xaml library version

Comment: You can find the version of this lib in the NuGet package explorer (in the context menu of your UWP project -> Manage your NuGet packages)

Comment: Thanks. Ive figured out that the package was not correctly installed :) I think it's working now

Answer (score 1):

Add following xaml code into App.xaml will solve your problem.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"/>
</Application.Resources>
```